# Computing the geometric median

Tags: code-golf, geometry

Given a list of integer points in an *n*-dimensional space, output the [geometric median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median). Note that the output is not necessarily integer. Your answer must be precise to at least two digits after the decimal point.

You may assume that *n* < 16 and that every component of each point fits in a 32-bit signed integer.

You may write a program or a function. You may take input and give output in any reasonable format. You may optionally pass *n* as a separate argument, instead of having to deduce it.

You must implement an algorithm to compute the geometric median, and not brute force over the output domain.

Examples:

```
(5), (14), (10), (7)                         -> any 7 <= x <= 10 is valid
(2, 3), (8, 4), (12, -3), (0, 0), (0, 0)     -> (2.17, 1.29)
(0, 0, 3), (20, 7, 3), (13, 14, 15)          -> (13.18, 7.94, 7.23)
(2, 20, 3, 30), (20, 2, 20, 2), (1, 2, 3, 4) -> (5.46, 5.12, 6.84, 8.06)
```

The answer is only unique if the set of points do not lie on a line. If the answer is not unique, you may return any valid answer.

Comment: Any requirement on complexity? Double-loop from `min` to `max` with step `0.01` will probably do the job. Is this allowed? (not sure whether it's less or more fun)

Comment: @anatolyg You must not brute force over the output domain. (Previously I stated that your solution mustn't rely on the input domain, but this unfairly rules out some probabilistic / hill climbing algorithms).

Comment: An accuracy of two decimal points isn't meaningful without some bound on the input coordinates. Perhaps when you say "integers" you mean 32-bit signed integers? Also, how do you expect us to confirm that our iterative algorithm is sufficiently accurate? Is it OK to just check this on the test points? I haven't found a proof of a formal quantitative bound of the Weiszfeld's algorithm in the worst case.

Comment: @xnor 32-bit signed integers as input bound is fine. Similarly, let's say that _n_ < 16. Sadly I do not know the answer to your second question. I do not consider just these 4 test cases enough, though.  If someone finds another counterexample to your answer you must fix it.

Comment: @xnor A proven algorithm does exist however: http://www.pnas.org/content/97/4/1423.full.pdf. You can see my implementation (without weights, just like the challenge) here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30305181/565635.

Comment: @orlp I'm not seeing a rate of convergence in that paper though, just a claim of the correct limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Matlab, <s>77</s> 75

I just use the definition of the geometric median with a numerical minimization. In this case I make use of the Nelder-Mead simplex algorithm. It sould always converge as we try to find the minimum of a convex function (according to Wikipedia).

```
n=@(m)trace((m'*m).^.5);f=@(m)fminsearch(@(y)n(bsxfun(@minus,m,y)),m(:,1))
```

Old version:
    n=@(m)sum(diag(m'*m).^.5);f=@(m)fminsearch(@(y)n(bsxfun(@minus,m,y)),m(:,1))

The input format is a matix with the input vectors as columns, e.g:

```
m = [[2; 20; 3; 30],[20; 2; 20; 2],[1; 2; 3; 4]];
```